# Ajax response returns empty value. Network response shows the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, angularjs

I'm having a really weird problem where a certain value from an ajax json response is an empty string. All other values are coming through fine.

The weird part is that when I look at the response in the network panel it shows the correct value.
By the time I console log it, it's empty.

I'm really not sure where to begin at debugging this.

It's a pretty simple ajax call. I'm using a factory and logging the response.

```
getAllActivity: function(){
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/getActivity'
    });
}

feedFactory.getAllActivity().success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

The response from the log shows:

```
{
    "__type": "ActivityService",
    "activityTime": "/Date(1414189623937-0600)/",
    "activityTimeString": "2014-10-24T16:27:03.9370000-06:00",
    "activityType": "Appreciation",
    "activityUrl": "~/Blog/August-2014/Staggering-the-Line",
    "activityUser": {
      "userId": 12345,
      "userNickName": "Mike_Jones"
    },
    "itemDescription": ""
}
```

The response from the network panel shows:

```
{
    "__type": "ActivityService",
    "activityTime": "/Date(1414189623937-0600)/",
    "activityTimeString": "2014-10-24T16:27:03.9370000-06:00",
    "activityType": "Appreciation",
    "activityUrl": "~/Blog/August-2014/Staggering-the-Line",
    "activityUser": {
      "userId": 12345,
      "userNickName": "Mike_Jones"
    },
    "itemDescription": "test"
}
```

Also, it's working fine on other activityTypes. The object is exactly the same, the only difference being the value isn't returned as an empty string.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks to Michal in the comments I was able to see the value by using `console.log(angular.copy(response));`

However when I try to use that `var foo = angular.copy(response); function doWhatEva(foo);`
Inside doWhatEva it is empty again.

Comment: What type of response do you need in your request? Json, xml, etc

Comment: Based on your comments below, the omitted items may not seem relevant, but there might be a cause for error in there. Or, you could try to stringify your JSON down to the console -- `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: When I stringify the response it shows the value as null.

Comment: Do you have any $http response transformers?

Comment: I haven't added any response transformers.

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you do `console.log(angular.copy(response))` ?

Comment: What is the response when the itemDescription value is not "test", the same? have you tried with different data and types.

Comment: @MichalCharemza - it does work when I use angular.copy! It shows up in the log, I mean. How do I go about using this as a solution though? I tried this: response = angular.copy(response)); but that threw an error. Also, what is angular.copy doing?

Comment: @Venkat - When it's not test it's null. This one of about 25 other factory methods and everything else is working as expected. There are other services using this same field and it's working there.

Comment: @Kolby if you are serializing the data, can you please give the model meant for this.

Comment: @Venkat I'm not doing any serializing. The response is coming back as an object and I'm setting the object to a scope variable.

Comment: @Kolby did u try specifying the content type for the get response?

Comment: @Venkat, no I'm using the default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' Would you suggest I try something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63718/discussion-between-venkat-and-kolby).

Comment: If `angular.copy` is showing the right thing, it suggests that the value is being changed afterwards. Is it being used in a controller or directive somewhere that might be modifying it?

Comment: I'm doing the console.log as soon as I get the response back.

Comment: I've found that sometimes console.log shows objects as they are at the end of the current event loop. The copy forces the log to behave as expected, and show the value as of the moment you call console.log. You can also try setting a breakpoint in the response handler, and examine the response variable, to see if this is in fact what's happening.

Comment: Well I've tried commenting out the next line where I send the response to a function to mess with the data before setting it to scope. Even with nothing but the console.log in the success function it logs the same results. Oh waitttt, I think you are right. I tried again and it's showing up now, let me look through this function and see what could be causing it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the output from

```
console.log(response)
```

was missing the value, but the output from

```
console.log(angular.copy(response))
```

had the missing value present. Because `console.log` can show objects not as they are at the time of calling `console.log`, but at the end of the JS event loop, this suggests that the value was returned from the server properly, and Angular was decoding it fine from the JSON, but that the value was being changed later, in some code not contained in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `dataType:json` to your request

`getAllActivity: function(){
    return $http({
 type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
url: '/getActivity'
});
}`

Comment: But, if you debbug the code, the method in your server side is returning something? Or at least is accessing to your method?

Comment: yup it's returning a json response with all the other expected data, except that one value.

Comment: Can you paste the excepted data and the current data answered for the server

Comment: The unique possible reason that I can see in this moment is the json, the last comma `,` after the `uniqueNickname` and `itemDescription` can be the cause of the error. Remove the last comma `,` in each one.

Comment: sorry there's no commas there, just forgot to remove the comma. There's other information after that, that isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It should be useful to see what is doing and returning "getActivity" url, maybe the value for itemDescription is coming up with a weird character or something.

Comment: It's simply pulling a value from the database. I put in a breakpoint to make sure there was no weird characters, it's just the string "test" as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a deserialization problem because that is not a valid json:

```
"activityUser": {
      "userId": 12345,
      "userNickName": "Mike_Jones",
    }


"userNickName": "Mike_Jones",
```

There is a comma more, did you already fix that ?

Comment: yes sorry for that. I edited the object to make it smaller as an example. The json is valid.

Answer (score 0):

try this, should works:

`getAllActivity: function(){
     var result = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/getActivity'
     });
     return (result.then(function(r){return r.data}));
    }`